# VB.NET Mouse Hover Glitch?

Tags: vb.net, hover, mouse

So I'm working on this simple little program and I'm down to the aesthetics of it. Now, I've dabbled with VB since high school, so over 6 or so years, but I'm by no means a genius with it However, I know my way around quite well.

I have a mouse hover event set to make the alpha channel (or in this case, and soon to be changed, background color of the button) ever so slightly fade in to give a smoother effect, more metro, etc.

But the problem is with anything I do on that mouse hover event, there's about a 500 ms delay before that code initiates. Any thoughts?

I'm about 99% positive it's not the code inside the event as I've tried different code doing completely different things.

It's juts annoying, so thoughts? :)

Thank you!

Comment: MouseHover only fires when it detects that you have stopped moving the mouse over the control i.e. You are hovering over it. Just like showing a tooltip. Imagine if it didn't do this:- tooltips would be popping up all the time as you moved your mouse over the top of a control

Answer (score 2):

The MouseHover event doesn't occur immediately. The events you're looking for are [MouseEnter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseenter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [MouseLeave](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseleave%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Mouse events on controls occur in this particular order:

1. MouseEnter
2. MouseMove
3. MouseHover / MouseDown / MouseWheel
4. MouseUp
5. MouseLeave